# Position a div adjacent to another div using float?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
/*First Div*/
#box1 {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 900px;
}
/*Second Div*/
#box2 {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 430px;
}

/*Third Div*/
#box3 {
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 430px;
}

/*Fourth Div*/
#box4 {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 900px;
}
```

I am having an issue with placing the thrid div to the right of the second div. How would I accomplish doing this? tried using an absolute/fixed position as a previous solution to float but had an issue with zooming out/in.

Comment: can you post your html structure please? And a code snippet

Comment: I don't see where you tried floating or positioning.

Comment: @j08691 My bad - I left a part out on #box3.

Comment: @AlexChar What do you want to see. The structure is essentially four seperated divs within a body

Answer (score 1):

You can float both divs which will set them next to each other. Be sure to give it a width, I use percentages so that the layout is more responsive / fluid.

```
#box2 {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 48%;
    float: left;

}

/*Third Div*/
#box3 {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#box2 { 
     width: 49%;
     display: inline-block; 
     vertical-align: top;
  }

  #box3 { 
     width: 49%;
     display: inline-block; 
     vertical-align: top;
  }
```